Kubernetes route traffic through Service outside cluster
I want to access an internal website through a kubernetes cluster which is accessible from a user via https.
In Detail:
We have a group of users which have restricted access to our kubernetes cluster. The cluster itself has access to an externalService (website). The users can't access the website directly.
My idea was that a kubernetes-service or pod could tunnel the traffic. So I don't need a redirect, which I successfully tried with an externalService.
Maybe a simple example helps to understand my needs:
User A can access the url my-internal-website.kubernetes-cluster.com which can be handled by an ingress rule inside the kubernetes-cluster.
User A can't access the url https://internal.url directly.
The kubernetes-cluster itself  (nodes) can access the url https://internal.url
I would like to route the traffic from A to the kubernetes-cluster (via ingress rule my-internal-website.kubernetes-cluster.com to a pod or service which retrieves the url https://internal.url and "replaces" links etc. with my-internal-website.kubernetes-cluster.com for navigation purposes.
In addition the cluster can only access the url https://internal.url using a http proxy.
Do you have any suggestions how to solve that? I tried with ExternalName services, but only implemented a redirect which won't work in my scenario.
Many Thanks

refer this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts which may help to resolve the issue, if not I'm happy to assist

The architecture design pattern that you just explained is what commonly called as "reverse proxy" and it is not exclusive for Kubernetes only. In fact, it is so widely used that you can find quite a number of either subscription services or self-hosted softwares that can perform the reverse proxy functionality without you having to re-invent the wheel.
One of the most popular software that can be used as a reverse proxy is NGINX. For your use case, you can just deploy NGINX as a common application inside your Kubernetes cluster using Deployment. You may refer its official guide on the details on how to use NGINX as a reverse proxy, but in general here are some concepts that you need to know before you jump into the implementations:

The website with URL https://internal.url is referred to as an "upstream server"
When NGINX proxies traffics to the upstream servers, it overwrites two HTTP headers: "Host" and "Connection", the former is a very important header with which many servers depend on it to perform the routing to the corresponding websites.
For example for your scenario, even though the traffics reach the NGINX proxy servers with the "Host" header of my-internal-website.kubernetes-cluster.com, NGINX will overwrite the header with internal.url which is what the upstream server recognize itself as.
This will result in any absolute URLs such as internal hyperlinks or media linking to be prefixed with internal.url which will cause the navigation and media loading to be broken from the end user POV.
To fix this, either:

you need to make the website only uses relative URLs for its internal hyperlinks and media linking which will make the end user browser prefixed them with the URL as known as the browser which is my-internal-website.kubernetes-cluster.com
or you need to make both the upstream website to read the "X-Forwarded-Host" and the NGINX to put the original "Host" value into that header. All the  internal hyperlinks and media linking will need to use that header value as the prefix.



